# Extract the spec file out of an RPM

Tags: centos, rpm

I have an RPM that I built. And I am looking to figure out how to extract the Spec file out of it. I have tried:

```
rpm --scripts -qp sampleBuild.rpm
```

That didn't work. Does anyone know the proper command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually, only source rpms have a spec file. You can extract it with

```
rpm2cpio myrpm.src.rpm | cpio -civ '*.spec'
```

or you can install the src rpm, as a user, with `rpm -i myrpm.src.rpm`, when
the directory `rpmbuild/SPECS/` will get the spec file.

Comment: Download the source-rpm with `yumdownloader --source yourpackagename`.

Answer (score 8):

I did some more digging around and while I cannot extract the SPEC file into another file such as text, I can use `rpmrebuild` to view the SPEC file and edit it. So, with that being said, here is the command I used:

`rpmrebuild -e -p sampleBuild.rpm`

Comment: This works well for RPMs (not SRPMs) where the original spec is missing, as it generates a fake spec. The yum package is `rpmrebuild`.

Comment: Works fine on CentOS 6.10 provided you've rpmrebuild(available in EPEL repo not in base repo) installed. You may download epel rpm from here: https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm